# Something unclear about central limit theorem / law of large numbers

Tags: probability

Say I have $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +...+X_n$ where $X_i \sim Ber(1/2)$. Then:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|S_n-\frac{n}{2}|<\frac{\sqrt n}{2})\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} P(|M_n-\frac{1}{2}|<\frac{1}{2\sqrt n}) \to 0$$
Where I denoted $M_n = S_n/n$  and the probability goes to zero because for $n\to \infty$, $\frac{1}{2\sqrt n} \to 0$. But if I instead use the central limit theorem:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|S_n-\frac{n}{2}|<\frac{\sqrt n}{2})\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} P(|\frac{S_n-\frac{n}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt n}{2}}|<1) = 2\phi(1)-1$$
And what I received doesn't go to $0$ when $n\to \infty$. What have I done wrong?

Comment: The law of large numbers implies $P(|M_n-1/2| < \epsilon) \to 1$ for fixed $\epsilon > 0$. I don't believe it implies anything about $P(|M_n-1/2| < \epsilon_n)$ for $\epsilon_n \to 0$.

Comment: However for random variables with finite variance, Chebyshev's inequality implies $P(|M_n-\mu|<\epsilon_n) \to 1$ as long as $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \epsilon_n = \infty$. CLT tells you that you should expect a result strictly between zero and one if $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{n} \epsilon_n=L$ where $L \in (0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

The law of large numbers tells you that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n-1/2=0$$ almost surely, i.e.,
$$\mathsf P\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} M_n-1/2=0\right)=1,$$
but this does not imply that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf P\left(\lvert M_n-1/2\rvert>1/(2\sqrt n)\right)=0.$$